# Поиск в MongoDB, C# драйвер

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio-2015

Мучаю MongoDB в Visual Studio 15 с C# драйвером последней версии. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не находит ни одного документа ? Пробую так.

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gt("delta", 0);

foreach (BsonDocument indication in indicators1.Find(filter).ToEnumerable<BsonDocument>())
```

Создаю фильтр, чтобы графа *delta* в документах была больше нуля, результат в цикле перебираю. Кстати, ещё директива

```
using FluentAssertions;
```

Не работает. Не находит её.

П.С.
Когда меняю фильтр на "не равно нулю", в каждом цикле для вывода коллекции выводит все документы, включая те, в которых указанный параметр равен нулю...

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gt("delta", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем, о чем я забыл, так это о том, что в базе всё хранится в string, а критерий поиска, как видно, int. Потому и результаты не совпадали с ожидаемыми:)
Ноль в инт и ноль в стринг - не одно и тоже

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим Вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/57879)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin пожалуйста, будьте внимательнее. Это именно авторский ответ на свой вопрос, а не дополнение.